# Where can I find an official source for one-liner command line tools available through pip install?

Tags: python, powershell, pip, windows-10

More specifically, I have been using speedtest-cli in Windows PowerShell. I was able to get this tool by using "pip install speedtest-cli". This tool tests my upload and download speed simply by entering "speedtest-cli" in PowerShell. Is there an official repository with similar one-liner command line tools akin to "speedtest-cli"? If so, where?

I am using the following Python and Pip versions:

Python 3.7.2

pip 18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `pip install` a package, you're getting it by default from [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index). So searching for *speedtest-cli pypi* will quickly lead you here:

https://pypi.org/project/speedtest-cli/

As for CLIs, check out [Awesome-CLIs](https://github.com/agarrharr/awesome-cli-apps).

For Python-specific tools, many are listed in the [Awesome-Python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python) library.